# Перейдите по ссылке/позвоните по телефону — ставить ли двоеточие?

Tags: двоеточие

Помогите, пожалуйста. В выражениях вроде: *перейдите по ссылке* (после стоит ссылка), *позвоните по телефону* (после указан номер телефона) нужно ли двоеточие после слов "ссылке"/"телефону"? Мне кажется, что необходимо. Но не могу найти правило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы поставил двоеточие перед ссылкой (перейдите по *следующей* ссылке), если она плохо запоминающаяся или представляет собой набор непонятных знаков, а перед телефоном бы не стал, поскольку воспринимаю его как аналог имени или названия. Сравните:

- позвоните по телефону +79261234567,
- обратитесь к дежурному Васе.

Answer (score 4):

**Ссылка и номер телефона — это определения при существительных** *ссылка, телефон, номер*. *Пройдите по ссылке (какой?), позвоните по номеру  (какому?)*. **Двоеточие ставить не нужно.**

Ср. ***Пройдите по этой ссылке: (а именно какой?) далее ссылка; позвоните по этому телефону: (а именно какому?) далее номер телефона***.  Здесь информация после двоеточия — уточняющая при определении *этот, такой, следующий и т. д.* (именно какой?), поэтому знак нужен.

Comment: Нельзя сказать "позвоните по **этому** номеру" с указанием номера дальше.